# Only call method when object is not null

Tags: android, null, gps

Lets say that i have an object that asynchronously will be seted (an user GPS position for example).
Is there a way to only call a method in an Activity when this object is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to call a method if some object is not null then:

```
if (myObject != null) { callMyActivityMethod()}
```

---

Based on your updated information, you only want to call the method once you have received a location from the GPS.

A [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) is used for receiving notifications from your [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

Create a `LocationListener` and pass it in your `requestForLocationUpdates()`. It will then notify you when a new location has been received. For Example:

```
LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            callMyActivityMethod();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
    };
...
requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locListener);
...
```

Comment: Ok, of course i have tought in this, but not solves, because if after this, my object is seted, and its not null anymore?

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail then. I have answered the question "Is there a way to only call a method in an Activity when this object is not null?", based on the information supplied so far.

Comment: I have a class that use GPS in Android. When i call the method in the activity to active the GPS it takes a time to get the first location of the user. Few lines after i call a method to get the location and put it in a map. But when i get, its null. So...i want a way to only call the method to get position when its not null. Im thinking about to use a thread, but if it theres other way...

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation. This can be easily handled. I'll update my answer.